# Take screenshot from WPF

Tags: wpf, element, screenshot

Is it possible to take screenshot of the single element on WPF form? I need to take screenshot of a "border" tool and its child.

Answer (score 2):

considering ***source*** to be the element that you want to take a screenshot.  This is the code that I have which saves it to the clipboard.

```
        RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)source.ActualWidth, (int)source.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bmp.Render(source);
        Clipboard.SetImage(bmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) to render visuals, if you search for it on SO there should be some questions that help if the reference is not enough.

Further [this external article](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/150676.aspx) might help.